# Como acessar os dados em uma variavel do tipo double[ , , ] em C#

Tags: c#, array, array-multidimensional

Estou estudando C# e em um [determinado código](https://github.com/Kenandeen/machine-learning/blob/master/TowersOfHanoi/TowersOfHanoi/QLearning.cs) me deparei com a seguinte situação:

```cs
double[,,] R = new double[_StatesMaxCount, 3, 2];
```

Em todo tempo que estou estudando, eu nunca vi esse tipo de declaração e não sei como usá-la. Alguém poderia me explicar para que serve esse tipo de declaração e qual o propósito desse código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá! Conforme [documentação da linguagem](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) esta linha de código declara um array multidimensional. Um exemplo:

```
double[,] R = new double[3, 2];
```

Declarei um array R multidimensional de tamanho 3x2. Note que o uso da vígula indica que o array será bidimensional.

No caso do seu código é declarado um array R, utilizando 2 vírgulas, ou seja, um array tridimensional.

O acesso aos elementos de arrays multidimensionais pode ser feito, como no exemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine(R[1, 0]); //Acessando um array bidimensional na posição 1,0 e mostrando seu valor em tela
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementando o que Ladynoob explicou, você pode iterar as dimensões dum <strike>vetor</strike> matriz e brevemente seus elementos. Na base da linguagem, você acaba tendo uma matriz posições interpoladas.

```
    int[,] v = new int[,] {
        {125, 634, 84, 12},
        {63, 78, 23, 3}
    };

    for(int x = 0; x < v.GetLength(0); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < v.GetLength(1); y++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"V => X = {x} Y = {y} V = {v[x, y]}");
        }
    }
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sw0aHn).</sup>

No exemplo acima, iterei uma matriz bidimensional. Nesse exemplo você itera uma matriz de três dimensões:

```
    int[,,] v = new int[,,] {
        {
             {1, 2},
             {3, 4},
             {5, 6}
        },
        {
             {7, 8},
             {9, 10},
             {11, 12}
        },
        {
             {13, 14},
             {15, 16},
             {17, 18}
        }
    };

    for(int x = 0; x < v.GetLength(0); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < v.GetLength(1); y++) {
            for(int z = 0; z < v.GetLength(2); z++) {
                 Console.WriteLine($"V => X = {x} Y = {y} Z = {z} V = {v[x, y, z]}");
        }
    }
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/buJAFr).</sup>

Com a função `v.GetLength(x)`, você recebe o tamanho total de elementos numa dimensão `x` da matriz `v`. Por exemplo, a propriedade `List.Count()` é um espelho ao `List.ToArray().GetLength(0)`.

Leia mais sobre o método [`GetLength`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=netframework-4.8).

Também existe uma diferença entre **vetor/matriz multidimensional** e **vetor de vetores**, que seria o caso de:

```
// vetor bidimensional
int[,] a = new int[,] { {10, 50}, {100, 150}, {200, 250} };

// vetor de vetores
int[][] b = new int[][];
b[0] = new int[] {10, 50};
b[1] = new int[] {100, 150};
b[2] = new int[] {200, 250};
```

Mas a forma de iterar também muda e você percorre um vetor dentro do outro, sem ter que lidar com dimensões no mesmo.

No código onde está seu exemplo, nós temos o seguinte método:

```
    private void InitRMatrix(int _StatesMaxCount)
    {
        R = new double[_StatesMaxCount, 3, 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < _StatesMaxCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                R[i, j, 0] = -1;
                R[i, j, 1] = -1;
            }
        }

        _Generator.StateActionMapping(R, _States, _StatesMaxCount, FinalStateIndex);
    }
```

`_StatesMaxCount` é diretamente o `R.GetLength(0)`, e os máximos das outras dimensões são literais **1** e **2**, portanto ao ter:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    R[i, j, 0] = -1;
    R[i, j, 1] = -1;
}
```

`j` é a posição na segunda dimensão do vetor, que vai apenas de zero à dois (`j < 3`), e o `0` e `1` na terceira dimensão é porque o tamanho dela é `2`.

Esse método irá fazer com que `R` tenha o valor `-1` em todos elementos em sua matriz, num tamanho fixo. É um método de inicialização de matriz. Você não pode acessar `R` sem ter iniciado o mesmo, como foi declarado:

```
private double[, ,] R;
```

Iria causar uma `NullReferenceException`. Por isso este método existe, para iniciar a matriz e ter valores na mesma.